# Open a Webpage, Log In, and Close it again

Tags: vba, excel, single-sign-on

I want to prepare daily reports from a particular JSON file. My plan is to download the file through VBA, then write a macro that automatically generates the report.

The problem is that the JSON file sit behind a Single-Sign-On authentication protocol. For various reasons I just do not want to VBA myself past the SSO.

What I would like to do is:
1) Have VBA open the address for the JSON file. 
2) If I'm not already signed-in, open the browser window for the SSO page so I can manually put in my credentials.
3) Once the JSON file is open - if I'm already signed on and the data is there, to close the browser window and download the data to a particular location.
4) call the other macro so the report can be generated.

A: Is this possible?

B: How?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes it is possible and a little bit messy. As I don't know how your system indicate a successful login, I am assuming the login page is directed to an authenticated page.

```
Dim IE

Set IE = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
IE.Visible = True
IE.Navigate "Your login page" 'Go to login page

Do
    DoEvents
Loop Until InStr(lcase(IE.LocationURL), lcase("Authenticated")) <> 0 ' wait until authentication is successful

IE.Navigate "your json url" ' Navigate to json url

Do
    DoEvents
Loop Until IE.ReadyState = 4 ' wait until download is completed

Debug.Print IE.Document.body.innerHTML '<-- your json

IE.Quit
Set IE = Nothing
```